# Can not define a constructor with parameters in ErrorHandler in angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, constructor

I am trying to create a shared service and use it from GlobalErrorHandler class which implements ErrorHandler but i get an error when i write the constructor with parameters.

```
metadata_resolver.js:972 Uncaught SyntaxError {_nativeError: Error: Can't resolve all parameters for GlobalErrorHandler: (?).
```

GlobalErrorHandler

```
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{

    constructor(private errorService:ErrorService){
        //When i write this without parameters no syntax error
    } 

    handleError(error){

        alert(error);
        console.log("handeled by GlobalErrorHandler")
        console.log("error",error);
        console.log("******************");
        //this.errorService.emitGlobalError("msgTest");
        //instead of logging to the console, i would like to call globalModal component and show the error in a popup
    }

}
```

Error Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {

    private globalErrorSource = new Subject<string>();
    globalErrorEmmitted= this.globalErrorSource.asObservable();

    emitGlobalError(msg){
            this.globalErrorSource.next(msg);
    }
}
```

appmodule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

  ],
  declarations: [

    ListMediaChannel,
    CrudMediaChannel
  ],
  providers: [SharedService, MovieCategoryService, MediaChannelService,ErrorService,
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: PathLocationStrategy
    },
    {provide:ErrorHandler,useClass:GlobalErrorHandler}

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Where did you provide `ErrorService`?

Comment: Inside appmodule in providers array  @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Does `ErrorService` have a constructor in your project or is it actually the same as in your question? I can't find any errors in the code in your question. I assume `GlobalErrorHandler` also has the `@Injectable()` decorator? I guess this needs a reproduction to investigate in Plunker or https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: GlobalErrorHandler doesnt have the injectable decorator and errorService doesnt have a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service classes with constructor parameters require `@Injectable()

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{
```

On your `ErrorService` it's optional, because it doesn't have constructor parameters.

Comment: Thanks it works now, could you please explain why or point me in the right direction ? @Günter

Comment: The `@Injectable()` decorator is used by Angular as marker to know what classes it needs to analyze for dependencies it needs to pass when it creates an instance. If there is no `@Injectable()` it assumes it doesn't expect to get passed anything, but that fails at runtime, because the constructor actually expects a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but howcome in components we don`t have @injectable but we can use a constructor with parameters which are injected ?

Comment: `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, and `@Pipe()` are recognized by DI the same as `@Injectable()`. `@Injectable()` is only required if a class doesn't yet have one of the former.